# Is there a correct way to measure speedup for iterative algorithm?

Tags: mapreduce, performance-testing

im planning to measure speedup the Jacobi method algorithm of Hadoop MapReduce version to handle very large data (20.000 ++ equation). As i know, Speedup refers to how much a parallel algorithm is faster than a corresponding sequential algorithm. 
i have implemented Jacobi method in hadoop mapreduce and sequential version,

My current technique to get speedup is comparing mapreduce and sequential version involve repeating execute mapreduce and sequential version in 30 times for performing 1 iterations.

Im wondering is there a best/correct way to do this ?

many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to focus on [**Amdahl's law**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) to do speedup analysis.

> My current technique to get speedup is comparing mapreduce and sequential version involve repeating execute mapreduce and sequential version in 30 times for performing 1 iterations.

This sentence is **not really clear to me**, can you reformulate?

If you have one matrix equation to solve compare sequential time T_1 and compare it to mapreduce time T_m(P) for P processes (I think you can use #cores for P) The speedup is then T_1/T_m.

Comment: thanks, i mean im doing the comparison by looking the execution times (mapreduce and sequential) of 30 iterations of this algorithm

Comment: Hm, I once solved matrix equitation in a research topic, if I understand correctly you probably mean that you are using an iterative approach to solving the matrix equation, and you grant 30 iteration to both approaches? This seems reasonable but I think using 1 iteration is the same since I assume every iteration uses the same amount of time. But maybe using 30 is better to lower the weight of less important processes on the runtime.